# How to escape "@" in markdown on bitbucket wiki

Tags: markdown, bitbucket

Anyone know how to escape the `@` character in markdown on BitBucket wiki?  In my case @ is immediately followed by the word which happened to be someone's user name, i.e. `@blahblah`.  What I've tried so far:

```
\@  
'@  
&\#64;
```

but none of those works. Shielding is just ignored, and when I'm using a character code, it just outputs it as is.

Comment: Why do you want to escape it? Just typing '@' should output '@'.

Comment: why would you need that outside a code block, which you can create with backticks like: \`@foo\`

Comment: @mb21 thx. That worked! Though, ideally would be good to have it as 'normal' text, not something highlighted as 'code'.

Comment: It's possible to disable @mentions in Confluence (Atlassians wiki software), but there is no option to do this in Bitbucket.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds strange, but you can insert an invisible character between `@` and text (e.g. [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)).

[image: MD code]
[image: Result]

Comment: and for anyone wanting to know how to enter a zero width space press `CTRL-SHIFT-U` to enter unicode mode and then enter `200B` (for the zero width space character)

Answer (score 8):

As @Mikalai mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34331584/470749), you can put a "zero width space" character between the `@` and the name. But I was having trouble following his instructions. It wasn't working for me.

### This was easy:

1. I clicked "Zero-Width Space (ZWSP) Character" at https://coolsymbol.com/, which copied that special character to my clipboard. (Thanks [@harryngh](https://superuser.com/a/1300582/74576))
2. Then I pasted the character after the @ symbol while typing my Bitbucket comment. It worked!

Answer (score 3):

For those who didn't read the comment on the original question (like me initially):

"why would you need that outside a code block, which you can create with backticks like: `` `@foo` ``" - mb21

Answer (score 3):

Our situation is related, a code snippet in Markdown with a JUnit test

````
```
@Test
public void testThis() throws Exception {
   //
}
```
````

It renders with the `@Test` annotation missing the `@` but enclosed in a box.

```
----------------------------------------
Test 
public void testThis() throws Exception {
  //
}
----------------------------------------
```

I don't understand why inside a code block the `@Test` is still interpreted as a user reference. I got around it by putting a space between `@` and the `Test`. It looks funny but gets the point across.